# Calculating number of quantum states in valence and conduction bands

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I am presented with the following question and have problems solving it, and would like to understand the meaning behind the question.

The question asks me to calculate the number of quantum states per cm cube in GaP in valence and conduction band. 
I understand that I will have to calculate the mass density and write down the electron configurations for both elements which I did.
Now I know that Ga shares the 3 valence electrons with P, and hence the states involved are 4p and hence 6N states where N is the number of atoms in a cm cube of GaP? Is this correct?

This is because I dealt with a simple Si semiconductor before.

For example for a Silicon semiconductor, I can determine that a-Si atom share four valence electrons (2 from its 3s and 2 from 3p states) to form a stable configuration, hence only the 3s and 3p states are involved, whereby the number of states, in this case, is 8N (2+6) from the 3s and 3p state, whereby the upper band contains 4N states and lower band aka the valence band contain 4N states.

So in the question I presented, I will need to calculate the number of atoms/cm^3 to find what is N first. Hence, first, amt of GaP = mass/Mr. Hence in 1cm^3, I can find that the amount = 4.13/(69.72+30.974) = 0.0410 mol = 2.469*10^22 atoms. So N = 2.469*10^22

Now here comes the problem, how many N states are there? Since now there are 2 elements, how do I combine them together to form a lattice if GaP does not have any spare valence electrons to bond with other GaP atoms to form the crystal lattice? How can I find what are the states involved in GaP for bonding with other GaP atoms?

Comment: Carrier concentrations are generally quoted on a per cubic centimeter basis, hence the request. So, you need to bring the density in to play in your answer.

Comment: @JonCuster Hi Jon, I updated my question after clarifying some of my concepts, was wondering if you can help me on that. Cheers